# Snakemake Megahit output issue

Tags: snakemake

A few days ago I started using Snakemake for the first time. I am having an issue when I am trying to run the megahit rule in my pipeline.

It gives me the following error "Outputs of incorrect type (directories when expecting files or vice versa). Output directories must be flagged with directory(). ......"

So initially it runs and then crashes with the above error. I implemented the solution with the directory() option in my pipeline but I think its not a good practice since, for various reasons, you can loose files without even knowing it.

Is there a way to run the rule without using the directory() ?

I would appreciate any help on the issue!

Thanking you in advance

```
sra = []

with open("run_ids") as f:
    for line in f:
        sra.append(line.strip())


rule all:
    input:
        expand("raw_reads/{sample}/{sample}.fastq", sample=sra),
        expand("trimmo/{sample}/{sample}.trimmed.fastq", sample=sra),
        expand("megahit/{sample}/final.contigs.fa", sample=sra)

rule download:
    output:
        "raw_reads/{sample}/{sample}.fastq"
    params:
        "--split-spot --skip-technical"
    log:
        "logs/fasterq-dump/{sample}.log"
    benchmark:
        "benchmarks/fastqdump/{sample}.fasterq-dump.benchmark.txt"
    threads: 8
    shell:
        """
        fasterq-dump {params} --outdir /home/raw_reads/{wildcards.sample}  {wildcards.sample} -e {threads}
        """

rule trim:
    input:
        "raw_reads/{sample}/{sample}.fastq"
    output:
        "trimmo/{sample}/{sample}.trimmed.fastq"
    params:
        "HEADCROP:15 TRAILING:3 SLIDINGWINDOW:4:15 MINLEN:36"
    log:
        "logs/trimmo/{sample}.log"
    benchmark:
        "benchmarks/trimmo/{sample}.trimmo.benchmark.txt"
    threads: 6
    shell:
        """
        trimmomatic SE -phred33 -threads {threads} {input} trimmo/{wildcards.sample}/{wildcards.sample}.trimmed.fastq {params}
        """

rule megahit:
    input:
        "trimmo/{sample}/{sample}.trimmed.fastq"
    output:
        "megahit/{sample}/final.contigs.fa"
    params:
        "-m 0.7 -t"
    log:
        "logs/megahit/{sample}.log"
    benchmark:
        "benchmarks/megahit/{sample}.megahit.benchmark.txt"
    threads: 10
    shell:
        """
        megahit -r {input} -o {output} -t {threads}
        """
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it is a bad design of the *megahit* software that it takes a directory as a parameter and outputs into a file in this directory with a hardcoded name. Flagging the filename with `directory()` doesn't solve the issue, as in this case what you expect to be a file with the *.fa* extension megahit treats as a directory. The rest of the pipeline is broken in this case.

But this issue can be solved in Snakemake like that:

```py
rule megahit:
    input:
        "trimmo/{sample}/{sample}.trimmed.fastq"
    output:
        "megahit/{sample}/final.contigs.fa"
    # ...
    shell:
        """
        megahit -r {input} -o megahit/{wildcards.sample} -t {threads}
        """
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. If I do what you suggest I am taking again the same error I am trying to avoid. **Outputs of incorrect type (directories when expecting files or vice versa). Output directories must be flagged with directory()**

Comment: My fault, I meant something different. Please see the updates in my answer. The idea is to put file in `output` and provide the directory as an explicit path.

Comment: Hello again... If I do that Im getting the following error:  megahit: Output directory /home/megahit/SRR11192682 already exists, please change the parameter -o to another value to avoid overwriting.

Comment: That is the problem of megahit, not Snakemake. Check that the directories don't exist. One more hit is to run Snakemake with the `--printshellcmds` parameter: that will show you all shell commands that the pipeline uses. You can run them one by one to locate the problem.

Comment: The "already exists, please change the parameter -o to another value to avoid overwriting" error is in a way a problem of the suggested Snakemake rule: Snakemake creates directories for output files automatically. The solution is to add the `-f` argument for megahit for it to ignore the fact that the directory gets created right before megahit is launched.

Answer (score 0):

A better design of the megahit rule would look as follows:

```py
rule megahit:
    input:
        "trimmo/{sample}/{sample}.trimmed.fastq"
    output:
        out_dir = directory("megahit/{sample}/"),
        fasta = "megahit/{sample}/final.contigs.fa"
    log:
        "logs/megahit/{sample}.log"
    benchmark:
        "benchmarks/megahit/{sample}.megahit.benchmark.txt"
    threads:
        10
    shell:
        "megahit -r {input} -f -o {output.out_dir} -t {threads}"
```

This guarantees that the output directory is removed upon failure, while the `-f` argument to megahit tells it to ignore the fact that the output folder exists (it is created by Snakemake automatically because one of the outputs is a file inside it: `final.contigs.fa`).

BTW, the `-m` (`--memory`) parameter is best implemented as a resource. The only problem though is that snakemake's default resource, `mem_mb` is in megabytes. One workaround would be as follows:

```py
    resources:
        mem_mb = mem_mb_limit_for_megahit # could be a fraction of a global constant
    params:
        mem_bytes = lambda w, resources: round(resources.mem_mb * 1e6)
    shell:
        "megahit ... -m {params.mem_bytes}"
```